# Python Multiprocessing queue is not getting all the elements to process

Tags: python, python-3.x

For all the Active campaigns, I have to query TSDB API for a date period to fetch data for each Campaign ID.so I get all the Campaign ids from the Db and put it to queue. In Db, I have 430 active campaign ids.

But python code is terminating after some 100 entries, don't know the reason, can somebody guide me here, but if I removed the API query fetching code and just prints the queue value get(q.get()), the Id value to fetch API is coming.

below is the code

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from datetime import date
import requests
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from  multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
from os import getpid
from time import sleep
from random import random

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='HOSTNAME',
    database='DB',
    user='ROOT',
    password='PASSWORD',
    port='PORT'
 )

print("Connection ID:", db.connection_id)


MAX_WORKERS=10

class Testing_mp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initiates a queue, a pool and a temporary buffer, used only
        when the queue is full.
        """
        self.q = Queue()
        self.pool = Pool(processes=MAX_WORKERS, initializer=self.worker_main,)
        self.temp_buffer = []

    def add_to_queue(self, msg):
        """
        If queue is full, put the message in a temporary buffer.
        If the queue is not full, adding the message to the queue.
        If the buffer is not empty and that the message queue is not full,
        putting back messages from the buffer to the queue.
        """

        if self.q.full():
            print("QISFULL",msg)
            self.temp_buffer.append(msg)
        else:
            self.q.put(msg)
            if len(self.temp_buffer) > 0:
                add_to_queue(self.temp_buffer.pop())

    def write_to_queue(self):
        """
        This function writes some messages to the queue.
        """
        mycursor = db.cursor()

        mycursor.execute("select Id from Campaign where Status='ACTIVE' order by Id desc")

        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in myresult:
            self.add_to_queue(x[3])
            sleep(random()*2)  
        db.close()   # close the connection


    def worker_main(self):
        """
        Waits indefinitely for an item to be written in the queue.
        Finishes when the parent process terminates.
        """
        print "Process {0} started".format(getpid())
        while True:
            # If queue is not empty, pop the next element and do the work.
            # If queue is empty, wait indefinitly until an element get in the queue.
            item = self.q.get(block=True,timeout=None)
            start_date=datetime.today()
            start_date=start_date.date()
            end_date = start_date - timedelta(days=8)
            start_date = start_date - timedelta(days=1)
            print "{0} retrieved: {1}".format(getpid(), item)
            #print("STARTDATE",type(start_date))
            start_date_ft=start_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
            ##print("ENDDATE",end_date)
            end_date_ft=end_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
            url = "http://tsdb.metrics.com:4343/api/query"
            if item is not None:
                querystring = {"start":end_date_ft,"end":start_date_ft,"m":"avg:1d-avg:percentization{campaign="+str(item)+",type=seen}"}
                print(querystring)
                response = requests.request("GET", url,params=querystring)
                print(response.text)
                if response and response.text is not None:
                    loaded_json = json.loads(response.text,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
                    for x in loaded_json:
                        for attribute, value in x.items():
                            if attribute is not None and attribute=="dps":
                                dps_data=loaded_json[0][attribute]
                                perValue=[]
                                if len(dps_data)>0:
                                    for key,val in dps_data.items():
                                        perValue.append(str(val))
                                        print(str(item)+"==ITEM=="+key+"="+str(val))

                                print(perValue)
            # simulate some random length operations
            sleep(random()*1) 

# Warning from Python documentation:
# Functionality within this package requires that the __main__ module be
# importable by the children. This means that some examples, such as the
# multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp_class = Testing_mp()
    mp_class.write_to_queue()
    # Waits a bit for the child processes to do some work
    # because when the parent exits, childs are terminated.
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: Perhaps exceptions were thrown in your "worker_main" after the 100th id? So perhaps it is the input data and not your current code's fault? Are there any error message when your program ended? Or you can run your program first and log the successful ids. In second round, only ids outside the successful ids are fed to the worker, so you can make sure whether it is the input data fault.

Comment: @dgg32 there were no error msg, as I have mentioned above, if I removed the code block of API fetching and just print the item, it will be getting printed, but if I included, not working as expected

Comment: @stovfl and I'm thinking, is there any issue abt the response getting from API??

Comment: @Chethu: This: ***`Pool(processes=MAX_WORKERS, initializer=self.worker_main,)`*** is **wrong**, you never start a `Task` in a `Process`. Read [Pool - examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#examples) how to use it.

Comment: @stovfl, oh, sorry I don't know abt that, this multiprocessing in python is totally confusing for me and yea,  will check again with examples. Thank you